# regex for number that starts with 0 but is not a decimal

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex for a number that starts with 0 but shouldn't match for decimals e.g. the regex should match `00909,050,000033` but shouldn't match `0.909`. This is the regex I used:

```
/[0]+\d+(?!\.)/g
```

It is flawed because it matches `0.909` which is not what I want. Also, if I have a string like `0009+045*0.909`, the regex should match `0009` and `045` but not `0.909`.

I appreciate anyone with a solution for this.

Comment: ou can use your regex but add `\b`: [`/\b0+\d+\b(?!\.)/g`](https://regex101.com/r/uF4aB0/1)

Comment: @Wiktor thanks your solution is very correct

Comment: @user3775998 - Wictor's solution is not correct, why do you say that?

Comment: @sln please can u tell me for what scenario the answer above doesn't work for so i can test it because currently all the strings i have tested the regex with, i get the correct result

Comment: @sln After trying different strings, u are right the above solution isn't correct. My bad

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to achive what you wanted,

```
/^0[0-9]+/g
```

The above will select a number in this pattern,

- string should start with `0`.
- And followed by 1 or more continuous numbers.

And the above mentioned regex can also be written as,

```
/^0\d+/g
```

Comment: might as well just `^0\d+`

Comment: @Rajaprabhu it doesn't work for a string like this  '0009+045*0.909'. for this string it matches 0009,045 and then matches 09 in 0.909. i want it to match the first 2 operands but not the last

Comment: @user3775998 You updated that part recently into your question. Let me frame a regex for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
/\D*(0\d+?)\D*/g
```

This will extract all instances of your pattern which are available as $1 ... $9

Comment: it doesn't work for this string '001*00344+0.909=54895'.  applying your regex to the string i get ["00", "*00", "09="] as the result. I want the result to be ["001", "00344"]. Thanks

Comment: Sorry.
    function foo(str) {  
        var re = /(^|\D+)(0\d+)/g;  
        var r=re.exec(str);  
        var res=[];  
        while(r!=null){  
              res.push(r[2]);  
              r=re.exec(str);  
        }  
       return res;  
    }  
    var str =  '001*00344+0.909=54895';   
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = foo(str);

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a word boundary to the start of your pattern ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF4aB0/1)):

```
/\b0+\d+\b(?!\.)/g
 ^^
```

See the regex demo. However, it will also fail to match numbers at the end of a sentence before the final dot. Then, use a more precise lookahead to fail matches before a `.` followed with a digit:

```
/\b0+\d+\b(?!\.\d)/g
         ^^^^^^^^
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF4aB0/2)

But ***the safest way*** (in case the number looks like `4.05`) is to use a more sophisticated pattern (to be used with `RegExp#exec()` in a loop to extract `match[1]` value):

```
/(?:^|[^\d.])(0+\d+)\b(?!\.\d)/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uF4aB0/3)

**Details:**

- `(?:^|[^\d.])` - non-capturing group matching the start of string or a non-digit and non-dot character
- `(0+\d+)\b` - 1+ zeros followed with 1+ digits (a whole word)
- `(?!\.\d)` - not followed with a `.` + a digit.

Code:

```js
var re = /(?:^|[^\d.])(0+\d+)\b(?!\.\d)/g; 
var str = 'should match \n00909\n050\n000033\n0009\n045\n0009+045\n but shouldn\'t match\n0.909\n4.05';
var res = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    res.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + str + "</pre>";
document.body.innerHTML += "<pre>" + JSON.stringify(res, 0, 4) + "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is constrain the boundaries from not matching a
dot nor digit before and after. The middle will then be valid.

Answer in capture group 1.

`(?:^|[^\d.])(0\d+)(?![\d.])`

```
 (?: ^ | [^\d.] )          # BOS or not digit nor dot
 ( 0 \d+ )                 # (1), Number that starts with 0
 (?! [\d.] )               # Not digit nor dot
```

Comment: i tried your solution with this string  '001*+00344+0.909=54895+09.' and the result is [ '001', '+00344' ] instead of [ '001', '00344' ]

Comment: @user3775998 - No, no, the answer is `001` and `00344` because that's what's in capture group 1. See `Answer in capture group 1`.

Comment: but that isnt the result i am getting anytime i run your code. i get 001 and +00344. have u tried running the code?

Comment: @user3775998 - I don't care what you mean by `run your code`. Capture group 1 will always contain digits and can't contain anything else. What I posted is raw regex that is transportable to any language.

Comment: well, i have tried your regex with with different strings and it doesn't give the exact result i want as I explained to u above