# Regexp to find JSON attribute name/key starting with digit only

Tags: json, regex, attributes, key

I am looking to find only this JSON attribute name/key which begins with digit irrespective of space.
`"4WD REGIONAL VALUE PACKAGE " : "42.2 ",`
`" 4WD REGIONAL VALUE3 PACKAGE7 " : " 42.2 ",`
`" WD_REGIONAL_VALUE_PACKAGE2332 " : "42.2 ",`
`"WD_REGIONAL_VALUE_PACKAGE2332 " : "42.2 ",`
`"447778WD_REGIONAL_VALUE_PACKAGE2332 " : "42.2 ",`

I have formulated a RegExp but it either matches only one attribute name when no global flag exists or when /g flag used then selects only digits in attribute names/keys which still is not fulfilling the task ask;
`(\d(?=[^,"]*[^\d]".*:))`

Ideal solution would be a regexp that selects and matches the first digit in above test data to give below attribute strings that are matched;
"**4**WD REGIONAL VALUE PACKAGE " : "42.2 ",
" **4**WD REGIONAL VALUE3 PACKAGE7 " : " 42.2 ",
"**4**47778WD_REGIONAL_VALUE_PACKAGE2332 " : "42.2 ",

Any pointers as to how to narrow down to the correct RegExp for the task is appreciated.

Comment: Like this? `"\s*\d[^"]*"\s*:\s*"[^"]*",?` https://regex101.com/r/56g3JK/1

Comment: Thanks @Thefourthbird for your inputs but as regex101.com result shows it does not matches my expected output.

Comment: It matches all 3 lines right? If you want the digit only you can use a capture group https://regex101.com/r/OdmMrP/1 What is the tool or language that you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the inputs of [regex for number that starts with 0 but is not a decimal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36667577/regex-for-number-that-starts-with-0-but-is-not-a-decimal), I modified my RegExp to use boundary
`(\b\d(?=[^,"]*[^\d]".*:))`
and it works for the usecase.

Comment: If you want to take the quotes into account and you are using Java you can do it like this https://regex101.com/r/2VIW2L/1 or with PCRE https://regex101.com/r/oSjSnq/1 or with JavaScript https://regex101.com/r/qKDJvk/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird, I do not expect quotes as well to be part of attribute name but good to know an alternative for worse case scenario. Thanks.